# Is it possible to use transform feedback to retrieve the triangles generated by an OpenGL vertex-geometry shader?

Tags: c++, opengl

I found a great transform feedback tutorial at:
https://open.gl/feedback

What I want is to be able to read the vertices emitted by the geometry shader, rather than using the geometry shader's out variables. I can use the out variables, but it's a bit of a hack.

Is this possible?

The code is:

```
const GLchar* vertexShaderSrc = R"glsl(
    #version 150 core

    in float inValue;
    out float geoValue;

    void main()
    {
        geoValue = sqrt(inValue);
    }
)glsl";

// Geometry shader
const GLchar* geoShaderSrc = R"glsl(
    #version 150 core

    layout(points) in;
    layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;

    in float[] geoValue;
    out float outValue;

    void main()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            outValue = geoValue[0] + i;
            EmitVertex();
        }

        EndPrimitive();
    }
)glsl";
```

...

```
// Create query object to collect info
GLuint query;
glGenQueries(1, &query);

// Perform feedback transform
glEnable(GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD);

glBindBufferBase(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, tbo);

glBeginQuery(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_PRIMITIVES_WRITTEN, query);
    glBeginTransformFeedback(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 5);
    glEndTransformFeedback();
glEndQuery(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_PRIMITIVES_WRITTEN);

glDisable(GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD);

glFlush();

// Fetch and print results
GLuint primitives;
glGetQueryObjectuiv(query, GL_QUERY_RESULT, &primitives);

GLfloat feedback[15];
glGetBufferSubData(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(feedback), feedback);

printf("%u primitives written!\n\n", primitives);

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    printf("%f\n", feedback[i]);
}
```

Comment: `the vertices emitted by the geometry shader, rather than using the geometry shader's out variables` what is in you opinion the difference between reading the out values and getting the emitted vetices?

Comment: I'd rather go the simplest route. That way I don't have to have all of those extra variables.

Comment: How do I read that output then?

Comment: @shawn_halayka The output is written to a [Transform Feedback Buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Transform_Feedback). This is the "simple" rout there is not shortcut. Which "extra variables."?

Comment: The values stored in the `out` variables describe the vertex that is passed by `EmitVertex` to the next stage in the rendering pipeline (e.g. the TransformFeedback) , without the `out` variables the generated Vertex would not have any data. And the `out` variables are the one you retrieve with the transform feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Please see the code that I linked to if you have questions about the source.

Comment: Right. OK, will do.

Comment: @shawn_halayka What's wrong with the code? The code works fine. What do you want to change?

Comment: There's no problem with the code, except that it doesn't read the primitives directly. If you don't know if you can do it, that's fine.

Comment: `except that it doesn't read the primitives directly` in the question you ask about vertices, now you talk about primitives. It is not really clear what you want to achieve. What do you mean by threading them directly? What would in your opinion be a more direct reading than reading the values that are the output of the geometry shader?

Comment: @shawn_halayka *"If you don't know if you can do it, that's fine."* - We don't guess here. We know that it can't be done. We just try to find out what you want to achieve.

Comment: @shawn_halayka: This question makes no sense. The GS's output variables *define* the vertices emitted by the GS. Writing to output variables is *how* a GS writes vertices. There is no distinction between the two. This question is like asking if you can see what color something is without using photons.

Comment: OK, there are two outs in my geometry shader. One's the triangle strip and one's the floating point variable. If I remove the floating point variable from the code, is there still a way to read the triangles back? If not, then I'll just make 3 floating point variables.

Comment: P.S. The code I pasted spits out 15 floating point numbers. That's only 1/3 of what's actually required to describe 5 triangles, so no, it's not spitting out the triangles.

Comment: So I changed the out type to a vec4, and it works well, as expected. But my question still stands: Do I really need to use an out variable like that, or is there a way to get the vertex data directly from the triangle strip out? Thanks for your time and patience while I figure this stuff out.

Comment: @shawn_halayka *"So I changed the out type to a vec4, and it works well, as expected. But my question still stands: Do I really need to use an out variable like that, or is there a way to get the vertex data directly from the triangle strip out [...]"* No, there is no way. How often do we have to repeat that?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Don't you think that it would be nice to have though? :)

Comment: @shawn_halayka See the OpenGL [Rendering Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview). You've misunderstood the concept.

Comment: @shawn_halayka what should be nice to have? `gl_Position` is an implicity `out` variable for the fragment shader,  that only exists in combination the fragment shader and not transform feedback. But it is still an `out` variable. If you want to read the output of the geometry shader on the host side you need to transphere it from the device to the host, so there for you need a buffer. If you use transform feedback you replace the implict `gl_Position` with an `out vec4 position`. So at which point do you think it could be made more direct (you constantly ignore this question)?

Comment: Somehow my comments vanished. Thanks for your help, everyone. I got it all working now, thanks to your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks again for all of the comments. A working code can be found at https://github.com/sjhalayka/opengl_gs_transform_feedback

The geometry shader is:

```
#version 430 core

layout (points) in;
layout (triangle_strip) out;
layout (max_vertices = 6) out;

out vec3 vert;

in VS_OUT
{
    vec4 position;
} gs_in[];

void main(void)
{
    vec3 vertex0 = vec3(1, 2, 3); 
    vec3 vertex1 = vec3(4, 5, 6);    
    vec3 vertex2 = vec3(7, 8, 9);

    vert = vertex0;
    EmitVertex();
    
    vert = vertex1;
    EmitVertex();
    
    vert = vertex2;
    EmitVertex();

    EndPrimitive();


    vertex0 = vec3(10, 11, 12); 
    vertex1 = vec3(13, 14, 15);    
    vertex2 = vec3(16, 17, 18);

    vert = vertex0;
    EmitVertex();
    
    vert = vertex1;
    EmitVertex();
    
    vert = vertex2;
    EmitVertex();

    EndPrimitive();
}
```

The pertinent C++ code is too long to be useful here.